Why PySpark `BinaryClasssificationEvaluator` metric `areaUnderROC` returns slightly different across multiple evaluations on the same dataset?
I am using BinaryClasssificationEvaluator in Pyspark to calculate AUC, however, I find that the returned auc across multiple evaluations on the same dataset are different(under the same dev enviroment, just click this cell in jupyter multiple times). That means, I cannot guarantee the result replication.
Due to privacy issue I cannot release the content of dataset data_sample_full_w_target_subexample_pd but its shape is 234225 where "bad" is 0/1 and "probability" is a double within [0, 1].
Here is the code
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import BinaryClassificationEvaluator
from pyspark.ml.classification import RandomForestClassifier
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler

import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T

# assuming I have a pandas dataframe `data_sample_full_w_target_subexample_pd` that column "bad" is the y_true and "prob" is the y_pred probability

# sort it to avoid ranking uncertainty
data_sample_full_w_target_subexample_pd_sorted = data_sample_full_w_target_subexample_pd[["bad", "prob"]].sort_values(by=["prob", "bad"], ascending=[False, True])

# pyspark to calculate auc
prediction = spark.createDataFrame(data_sample_full_w_target_subexample_pd_sorted)
prediction = prediction.withColumnRenamed("bad","label")

evaluator = BinaryClassificationEvaluator(
    labelCol="label", 
    metricName="areaUnderROC")
evaluator.setRawPredictionCol("prob")
areaUnderROC = evaluator.evaluate(prediction)


# pandas to calc auc
# RF_pred = prediction.select('label', 'prob').toPandas()
RF_pred = prediction.toPandas() 
probRF=[]
for i in range(prediction.count()):
    probRF.append(RF_pred['prob'][i])  #it takes only the probability for the label 1 

auc = roc_auc_score(RF_pred['label'], probRF)  # this will always return 0.9683804033270174

# auc and areaUnderROC should be SAME!
print(areaUnderROC)
print(auc)



However, the pandas version can produce the same auc result, regardless how many times I run it.
I believe there must be something happening at BinaryClassificationEvaluator, but from its documentation, there is no randomness mentioned in its parameter.
Any insight ? Thanks a lot!
